# 2D steady state heat and mass balance in cylindrical coordinate PDE discretization

Tags: python, algorithm, model

I am working on a model development for heat and mass transfer in a packed bed reactor with reaction (heat sink). The 2D graph as shown below, a inlet from the left with constant temperature and concentration, a wall at top with constant temperature, the bottom is a centreline (symmetric line) with no variation of temperature and concentration, and same for the outlet as right, which defined initial conditions and BC.

[image]

There are 3 equations, mass balance, energy balance and reaction rate coupled together.

[image]

I plan to use finite difference method to solve the PDE in Python.
First step, I discretize the equations using central difference approximation.

Mass balance:
[image]

Energy balance:
[image]

Reaction rate is not discretized as it always use the current T and C.

Question 1:
When I discretizing energy balance equation, do I have to move all the T[i,j] to the left as an unknown term? Because the energy balance includes a reaction rate term which is a function of T and C, and the T in reaction term is T[i,j]. The way I am doing now, I leave the reaction term at right because this Temperature is from the previous one in the node. I got a bit confused here.

Question 2:
The other question, I start the loop with calculating T using the initial condition, the loop will start with column by column. For example, first will calculate T[1, 1] using the four nodes around it, which has two nodes having known value, then will go T[2,1] until T[3,1]. The boundary condition for bottom and outlet is no variation, so I set T[-1,:] =  T[-2,:] for the bottom and T[:,-1] =  T[:,-2]. However, as the array is initialized with 0 value, these boundary condition affect the results, the value decrease to 0 whe  closing to the boundary. So, how to properly set the Neumann BC in Python?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvgtf.png)

Advice 1:
Would you please give some tips for how to literately solve these three equation?
Currently, I have one loop and solve the three equation in sequence.
I used the initial value to get a new temperature node by node, then use the temperature and initial concentration to get the reaction rate at this node. The new reaction rate is used to get an updated concentration. I am confused about the iteration..

I have attached my code below, it shows incorrect result though.
Your suggestion and advice would be highly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set total range
r_range = 10  # mm
z_range = 250

# Set grid size
grid_size = 1

# Calculate the number of points
num_points_r = int(r_range / grid_size) + 1
num_points_z = int(z_range / grid_size) + 1

# Set grid
r_start, r_end = 0, r_range
z_start, z_end = 0, z_range
r = np.linspace(r_start, r_end, num_points_r)
z = np.linspace(z_start, z_end, num_points_z)

# grid distance
dr = r[1] - r[0]
dz = z[1] - z[0]

# initialization of C, T
C = np.zeros((num_points_r, num_points_z))
# T = np.zeros((num_points_r, num_points_z))
T = np.ones((num_points_r, num_points_z)) * 570
ri = np.zeros((num_points_r, num_points_z))

# Initialize lists to store changes
residuals_C = []
residuals_T = []

# Set parameter
u_s = 0.0049  # superficial velocity m/s
# Der = 0.00000895  # effective radial diffusion coefficient m2/s
Der = 0.001
rho_catalyst = 4000  # kg/m3
rho_fluid = 704  # kg/m3
cp_fluid = 3037  # J/ kg K
lambda_er = 39.8  # effective radial thermal conductivity, W/ m K
delta_H = -65000  # J/ mol_H2
Ut = 10  # heat transfer coefficient W/ m2 K
Ts = 570  # wall temperature
A = u_s * rho_fluid * cp_fluid / 1000
# Set reaction parameter
k = 0.0108  # m3/kg s
# k = 0.00008  # m3/kg s
E = 117000 # J/mol
R_gas = 8.314  # J/mol K
H = 117000 # J/ mol H2

# Set initial parameter
C0 = 5134  # mol/m3 rho/MW   kg/m3 / kg/mol
T0 = 570  # K
C[:, 0] = C0  # inlet concentration
C[-1, :] = T[-2, :]
C[0, :] = C[1, :]

T[:, 0] = T0  # inlet temp
T[-1, :] = Ts  # constant wall temp, up boundary
T[0, :] = T[1, :]  # constant wall temp, lower boundary

# # Boundary conditions
T[:, 0] = T0  # inlet temp, left 570K
T[:, -1] = T[:, -2]  # outlet right
T[-1, :] = Ts  # constant wall temp, up boundary
T[0, :] = T[1, :]  # lower boundary
reaction = k * np.exp(-E / (R_gas * T0)) * C0   # initial reaction rate
print("Initial reaction rate ", reaction)

# iterative to convergence
tolerance = 1e-7
not_converged = True
iteration = 0
max_iterations = 1000

print("A:", A)

while not_converged and iteration < max_iterations:
    # Initialize C_new and T_new with the current state of C and T
    C_new = np.copy(C)
    T_new = np.copy(T)

    for j in range(1, num_points_z - 1):  # loop at z direction
        for i in range(1, num_points_r - 1):  # loop at r direction
            # Calculate new temperature
            T_new[i, j] = (1 / 2) * (T[i - 1, j] + T[i + 1, j]) + (dr / (4 * r[i])) * (T[i + 1, j] - T[i - 1, j]) - \
                          ((A * dr) / (4 * lambda_er)) * (T[i, j + 1] - T[i, j - 1]) - \
                          (H * reaction * rho_catalyst * dr**2) / (2 * lambda_er)

            # Calculate reaction rate using average of old and new temperature
            reaction = k * np.exp(-E / (R_gas * T_new[i, j - 1])) * C[i, j - 1]

            # Calculate new concentration
            C_new[i, j] = (1 / 2) * (C[i - 1, j] + C[i + 1, j]) + (dr / (4 * r[i])) * (C[i + 1, j] - C[i - 1, j]) - \
                          ((u_s * dr) / (4 * Der)) * (C[i, j + 1] - C[i, j - 1]) + (rho_catalyst * reaction) / (Der * 4 * r[i])

    # Check for convergence
    not_converged = np.max(np.abs(T_new - T)) > tolerance or np.max(np.abs(C_new - C)) > tolerance

    # Calculate residuals
    residual_T = np.max(np.abs(T_new - T))
    # residual_C = np.max(np.abs(C_new - C))

    residuals_T.append(residual_T)
    # residuals_C.append(residual_C)

    print(f"Residual for T in iteration {iteration}: {residual_T}")
    # print(f"Residual for C in iteration {iteration}: {residual_C}")

    # Update C and T
    # C = C_new
    T = T_new

    print(f"Iteration: {iteration + 1}")
    # print("Temperature:")
    # print(T)
    # print("Concentration:")
    # print(C)
    # print("------------------------")

    iteration += 1

# create 2D grid for plot
R, Z = np.meshgrid(r, z, indexing='ij')  # 修改为 'ij' indexing 以确保 R, Z 的形状与 T, C 匹配

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.contourf(Z, R, T, levels=100, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Temperature Distribution")
plt.xlabel("z")
plt.ylabel("r")

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.contourf(Z, R, C, levels=100, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Concentration Distribution")
plt.xlabel("z")
plt.ylabel("r")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(residuals_T)
plt.title("Residuals of T per Iteration")
plt.xlabel("Iteration")
plt.ylabel("Residual of T")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

z_index = num_points_z // 2  # Index corresponding to z = z_range/2

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# Subplot for z=0
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)  # 1 row, 2 columns, first subplot
plt.plot(r, T[:, 0], label=f'z = {z_start}')
plt.title("Temperature Trend at z = 0")
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.legend()

# Subplot for z=z/2
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)  # 1 row, 2 columns, first subplot
plt.plot(r, T[:, z_index], label=f'z = {z_start}')
plt.title("Temperature Trend at z = z_range/2")
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.legend()

# Subplot for z=250
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)  # 1 row, 3 columns, second subplot
plt.plot(r, T[:, -1], label=f'z = {z_end}')
plt.title("Temperature Trend at z = 250")
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am trying to figure out how to address the issue and understand the iteration algorithm.