# 2D Steady State PDE in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, modeling

Refer to my previous post:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76720895/2d-steady-state-heat-and-mass-balance-in-cylindrical-coordinate-pde-discretizati)

I wrote a code working now, but I do not know why the concentration is barely changing but the temperature still has profile.
As the reaction rate is the function of T and C, so I make a initial reaction rate and it is used to get the first T array. Then I use this T array to calculate C and Q until C converged. The new Q will be used back to calculate the new T until T converged.
Are you able to provide any advice based on the code below? It would be appreicated.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#                 Wall
#              -----------
#            | A   D   G |
#     Inlet  | B   E   H |  Outlet
#            | C   F   I |
#              ------------
#             Symmetric line


# Set total range
r_range = 0.01  # m
z_range = 0.1  # m

# Set grid size
grid_size = 0.001  # m

# Calculate the number of points
num_points_r = int(r_range / grid_size) + 1
num_points_z = int(z_range / grid_size) + 1

# Set grid
r_start, r_end = 0, r_range
z_start, z_end = 0, z_range
r = np.linspace(r_start, r_end, num_points_r)
z = np.linspace(z_start, z_end, num_points_z)

# grid distance
dr = r[1] - r[0]
dz = z[1] - z[0]

# initialization of C, T
# C = np.zeros((num_points_r, num_points_z))
C = np.ones((num_points_r, num_points_z))
# T = np.zeros((num_points_r, num_points_z))
T = np.ones((num_points_r, num_points_z)) * 1
Q_reaction = np.zeros((num_points_r, num_points_z))

# Initialize lists to store changes
residuals_C = []
residuals_T = []

# Set parameter
u_s = 0.0049  # superficial velocity m/s
Der = 0.00000895  # effective radial diffusion coefficient m2/s
# Der = 0.0000253856  # m2/s
rho_catalyst = 5000  # kg/m3
rho_fluid = 704  # kg/m3
cp_fluid = 3037  # J/ kg K
lambda_er = 3.98  # effective radial thermal conductivity, W/ m K
delta_H = 65000  # J/ mol_H2
Ts = 570  # wall temperature
A = u_s * rho_fluid * cp_fluid
# Set reaction parameter
k = 0.00005  # m3/kg s
E = 157000  # J/mol
R_gas = 8.314  # J/mol K

# Set initial parameter
C0 = 3622  # mol/m3 rho/MW   704 kg/m3 / 0.19435 kg/mol
T0 = 570  # K

# # Boundary conditions
T[:, 0] = T0  # Inlet
T[:, -1] = T[:, -2]  # Outlet
T[0, :] = T[1, :]  # lower boundary
T[-1, :] = T0  # constant wall temp, up boundary

C[:, 0] = C0  # Inlet
C[:, -1] = C[:, -2]  # Outlet
C[0, :] = C[1, :]  # lower boundary
C[-1, :] = C[-2, :]  # upper boundary

Q_reaction[:, :] = k * np.exp(-E / (R_gas * T0)) * C0  # initial reaction rate

print("Initial reaction rate [1][0] ", Q_reaction[1, 1])

# iterative to convergence
tolerance = 1e-6
not_converged = True
iteration = 0
max_iterations = 50

not_converged_2 = True
iteration_2 = 0
max_iterations_2 = 100

print("A:", A)

while not_converged and iteration < max_iterations:
    # Initialize C_new and T_new with the current state of C and T
    C_new = np.copy(C)
    T_new = np.copy(T)
    Q_reaction_new = np.copy(Q_reaction)

    for j in range(1, num_points_z - 1):  # loop at z direction
        for i in range(1, num_points_r - 1):  # loop at r direction
            # Calculate new temperature
            T_new[i, j] = (1 / 4) * (T[i - 1, j] + T[i + 1, j] + T[i, j - 1] + T[i, j + 1]) + (dr / (8 * r[i])) * \
                          (T[i + 1, j] - T[i - 1, j]) - ((A * dr) / (8 * lambda_er)) * (T[i, j + 1] - T[i, j - 1]) + \
                          (-delta_H * 6 * Q_reaction_new[i, j] * rho_catalyst * dr ** 2) / (4 * lambda_er)

            # print("after reaction", Q_reaction[i, j])

            # print("Temperature loop - [i, j]:", i, j)

    while not_converged_2 and iteration_2 < max_iterations_2:
        C_new = np.copy(C)
        Q_reaction_new = np.copy(Q_reaction)

        for j in range(1, num_points_z - 1):  # loop at z direction
            for i in range(1, num_points_r - 1):  # loop at r direction
                C_new[i, j] = (1 / 4) * (C[i - 1, j] + C[i + 1, j] + C[i, j + 1] + C[i, j - 1]) + (dr / (8 * r[i])) * (
                        C[i + 1, j] - C[i - 1, j]) - \
                              ((u_s * dr) / (8 * Der)) * (C[i, j + 1] - C[i, j - 1]) - (
                                      rho_catalyst * Q_reaction_new[i, j]) * \
                              dr ** 2 / (Der * 4)

                Q_reaction_new[i, j] = k * np.exp(-E / (R_gas * T_new[i, j])) * C_new[i, j]

        not_converged_2 = np.max(np.abs(C_new - C)) > tolerance
        residual_C = np.max(np.abs(C_new - C))
        residuals_C.append(residual_C)

        # print(f"Residual for C in iteration {iteration_2}: {residual_C}")

        C = C_new
        Q_reaction = Q_reaction_new
        C[0, :] = C[1, :]  # Symmetric axis, lower boundary
        C[-1, :] = C[-2, :]  # Upper boundary
        C[:, -1] = C[:, -2]  # Outlet

        iteration_2 += 1

    # Check for convergence
    not_converged = np.max(np.abs(T_new - T)) > tolerance

    # Calculate residuals
    residual_T = np.max(np.abs(T_new - T))
    # residual_C = np.max(np.abs(C_new - C))
    residuals_T.append(residual_T)

    print(f"Residual for T in iteration {iteration}: {residual_T}")
    # print(f"Residual for C in iteration {iteration}: {residual_C}")

    # Update C and T
    # C = C_new
    T = T_new

    # Update boundary
    T[0, :] = T[1, :]  # Symmetric axis, lower boundary
    T[:, -1] = T[:, -2]  # Outlet
    # C[0, :] = C[1, :]  # Symmetric axis, lower boundary
    # C[-1, :] = C[-2, :]  # Upper boundary
    # C[:, -1] = C[:, -2]  # Outlet

    print(f"Iteration: {iteration + 1}")
    # print("Temperature:")
    # print("Concentration:")
    # print(C)
    # print("------------------------")

    iteration += 1

    not_converged_2 = True
    iteration_2 = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 10))  # 2 rows, 1 column

# Temperature plot
img1 = ax[0].imshow(T, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', vmin=np.min(T), vmax=np.max(T),
                    aspect=0.5 * len(z) / len(r), extent=[z_start, z_end, r_start, r_end])

fig.colorbar(img1, ax=ax[0], format=ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:.7f}'.format(x)), label='Temperature (K)')
ax[0].set_title('Heat Distribution')
ax[0].set_xlabel('z')
ax[0].set_ylabel('r')

# Concentration plot
img2 = ax[1].imshow(C, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', vmin=np.min(C), vmax=np.max(C),
                    aspect=0.5 * len(z) / len(r), extent=[z_start, z_end, r_start, r_end])

fig.colorbar(img2, ax=ax[1], format=ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:.7f}'.format(x)),
             label='Concentration (mol/m3)')
ax[1].set_title('Concentration')
ax[1].set_xlabel('z')
ax[1].set_ylabel('r')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot residuals_T
plt.plot(residuals_T, label='Residuals T')

# Plot residuals_C
plt.plot(residuals_C, label='Residuals C')

plt.title('Residuals')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Residual')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

r_index_half = num_points_r // 2  # Index corresponding to r = r_range/2

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Subplot for Temperature
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)  # 1 row, 2 columns, first subplot
plt.plot(z, T[0, :], label=f'r = 0')
plt.plot(z, T[r_index_half, :], label=f'r = r_range/2')
plt.plot(z, T[-1, :], label=f'r = r_range')
plt.title("Temperature along z axis")
plt.xlabel("z")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.legend()

# Subplot for Concentration
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)  # 1 row, 2 columns, second subplot
plt.plot(z, C[0, :], label=f'r = 0')
plt.plot(z, C[r_index_half, :], label=f'r = r_range/2')
plt.plot(z, C[-1, :], label=f'r = r_range')
plt.title("Concentration along z axis")
plt.xlabel("z")
plt.ylabel("Concentration")
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Advice for

1. Why concentration is not (barely) changing,
2. why the concentration only change at the end of z axis?
3. Any better method to iterate this coupled PDEs?